# Calculating the Lyapunov exponents for the seir epidemic model

Tags: chaos-theory, complex-systems

I am trying to numerically calculate the Lyapunov exponents for the seir epidemic model given as:
$$
s^{'} = b - bs - \beta si  \\
e^{'} = \beta si - (\alpha + b)e \\
i^{'} = \alpha e - (\gamma + b) i \\
r^{'} = \gamma i - br \\
s + e + i + r = 0
$$

here, $\beta$ is the control parameter with $\beta = \beta_0(1+\beta_1 cos2\pi t)$.

Initially, I compute the derivatives as
$$
\frac{ds(t)}{ds} = - b - \beta i  \\
\frac{de(t)}{de} = \beta s - (\alpha + b) \\
\frac{di(t)}{di} = \alpha  - (\gamma + b)  \\
\frac{dr(t)}{dr} = - b \\
$$

After which, to compute the Lyapunov exponents, I use the formula $\lambda =  lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{t} ln |\frac{dF(t)}{dF}|$, where $\frac{dF(t)}{dF}$ are taken as the four equations represented above. As a result, I get four Lyapunov exponents. I integrate the system using an RK4 integrator for a given time period and average to find the maximal Lyapunov exponents for a chosen parameter $\beta$. However, I am certain the values that I attain are wrong since I get two positive Lyapunov exponents and two negative Lyapunov exponents, even for a periodic attractor. I am also confused about calculating the derivative since e and i are dependent on each other.

I think I do not grasp the theory very well. Can someone help me understand this better?

Comment: Attractors should have negative Lyapunov exponents. Presumably a periodic attractor should have spectrum (-,-,-,0) since for autonomous systems there is always one direction where orbits move in pace.

Comment: @AndersSandberg I'm sorry but I assumed only chaotic systems should have negative Lyapunov exponents while other systems should have positive spectrum?

Comment: @Jules No, it's the other way around: The LEs quantify the exponential _divergence_ of nearby phase space trajectories. So a positive LE denotes exponential divergence of nearby orbits (a condition for chaos) and a negative LE denotes exponential convergence (characteristic of attractors).

Comment: For the sake of readability it is worth explaining what is $F$, $fx$,$ \bar{x}$, etc. This is also likely a *check my homework* type of question.

Comment: @stafusa thank you, I definitely mixed them both up

Comment: @RogerVadim Okay! I have made the edits above. I am working on a project on modelling epidemic dynamics where it would be best to use Lyapunov exponents to confirm that my system is chaotic but I do not understand the theory very well to apply it which is probably leading to some errors in my numerical simulations.

Comment: @Jules As it is now, it is still not clear what you do: essentially, you are asking us to redo your calculations and publish the correct derivation. It would be better, if you showed more of your own derivations - you are more likely to get a response this way.

Comment: @RogerVadim sure, i have made some more edits on what I have achieved so far. Since my project is more computational, I am trying to understand the theory better.